# EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Temp table in oracle does not get created ORA-00942

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, execute-immediate

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706724/how-to-use-oracle-global-temporary-table) I was trying to create temp table, however I am getting exception `ORA-00942:table or view does not exist` I would assume there is something wrong with `'CREATE OR REPLACE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TempQandA(column1 number) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS'` statement, it fails on `insert into TempQandA(column1) VALUES (1);`.
Please find SQL statement below.

```
DECLARE 
TransactioDetailId numeric := 3132;
HomePhoneNumber varchar(20);
MobileNumber varchar(20);
Email varchar(20);
whatever varchar(20);
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TempQandA(column1 number) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS';

        BEGIN
        SELECT contactvalue into HomePhoneNumber  FROM customercontact CC
         inner join TRANSACTIONMAIN tm on tm.customerid = CC.customerid
         inner join transactiondetail td on td.transactionid = tm.transactionid
         where contacttypeid = 2 and td.transactiondetailid = TransactioDetailId;
         EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         HomePhoneNumber := NULL;
                         begin
                         SELECT  contactvalue into MobileNumber  FROM customercontact CC
                         inner join TRANSACTIONMAIN tm on tm.customerid = CC.customerid
                         inner join transactiondetail td on td.transactionid = tm.transactionid
                         where contacttypeid = 3 and td.transactiondetailid = TransactioDetailId;
                         EXCEPTION
                         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                         MobileNumber := NULL;
                                      begin
                                      SELECT  contactvalue into Email  FROM customercontact CC
                                      inner join TRANSACTIONMAIN tm on tm.customerid = CC.customerid
                                      inner join transactiondetail td on td.transactionid = tm.transactionid
                                      where contacttypeid = 1 and td.transactiondetailid = TransactioDetailId;
                                      EXCEPTION
                                      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                                      Email := NULL;

                                            begin
                                            insert into TempQandA(column1) VALUES (1);
                                             end;
                                     end;
                     end;
         end;
END;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *dynamically* create the `GTT`, so your `INSERT` too should be *dynamic*..

Note that, PL/SQL validates every static query before even executing it.
Thats why you get `ORA-942 Table or view doesn't exist` error  even at compilation time!

So, to escape this semantic check, we have to make the call dynamic.

```
    BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TempQandA(column1 number) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS';

.....

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' insert into TempQandA(column1) VALUES (1)';
    END;
```

And **Finally**, you *should not* be creating the `GTT` on run time.. To avoid such issues. The GTT is anyway going to *local* to every session.

**EDIT:** As Lalit says, `GTT`'s `DDL` doesn't accept `CREATE OR REPLACE`

Comment: GTT creation statement is incorrect. `OR REPLACE` is an invalid option.

Answer (score 2):

> 'CREATE OR REPLACE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TempQandA(column1 number) ON
>   COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS';

The keyword `REPLACE` is incorrect. You need to simply create the `GTT` and insert the values into it using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` :

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE Temp_gtt(column1 number) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS';
  3  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'insert into temp_gtt(column1) values(1)';
  4  END;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> select * from temp_gtt;

   COLUMN1
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Comment: Our both answers together, answers this question ;)

Comment: The first issue is with the create statement :-) Then later comes the insert.